# PHP MySQL : Matching mysql query result with php array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have some data on my database:

```
id_tag | tag
------------
1      | Dog
2      | Cat
3      | Buldog
4      | Persian Cat
```

Then i have a parameter:

```
$tag = "2, 4";
```

I want to show All of tags into checkbox. If the id_tag is equal the $tag parameter.
I have a trials:

```
echo "<div class='btn-group' data-toggle='buttons'>";
$thetag = explode(", ", $tag);
$tagall = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tags");
if(mysql_num_rows($tagall) > 0)
{
    while($tagt = mysql_fetch_array($tagall))
    {
        foreach($thetag as $ttg)
        {
            if($tagt['id_tags'] == $ttg)
            {
                $aktiv = "active";
                $ceked = "checked";
            }
            else
            {
                $aktiv = "";
                $ceked = "";
            }
        }
        echo "<label class='btn btn-primary {$aktiv}'><input type='checkbox' value='{$tagt['id_tags']}' autocomplete='off' {$ceked}> {$tagt['tag']}</label>";
    }
}
echo "</div>";
```

The result is:

```
Dog | Cat | Buldog | Persian Cat
```

with Persian Cat active and checked.

The result i need is Cat and Persian Cat active and checked. Please help me...!

Comment: Use checked="checked"

Comment: why do you have persian cat and cat as two categories? cat should consume persian cat. I guess you could look for 'Cat' in the tag label and if there is a match then set it to checked

Comment: Persian is the sub-category

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it is, because what you're doing here is looping through `$tag` inside the main loop pointlessly and each time you rewrite the previously stored information so only the last one is used.

Here's one of the solutions:

```
while($tagt = mysql_fetch_array($tagall))
    {
         if(in_array($tagt['id_tag'], $thetag))
            {
                $aktiv = "active";
                $ceked = "checked";
            }
            else
            {
                $aktiv = "";
                $ceked = "";
            }
        echo "<label class='btn btn-primary {$aktiv}'><input type='checkbox' value='{$tagt['id_tag']}' autocomplete='off' {$ceked}> {$tagt['tag']}</label>";
    }
```

In addition, please [consider avoiding mysql_* functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).

Comment: woow... I was not imagine about the in_array. I just focused about the foreach. Thanks guys. You are awesome.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `foreach ($thetag as $ttg)` loop keeps looping after it finds a match. If the next iteration doesn't match, it sets `$aktiv` and `$ceked` back to empty strings. The final value of these variables is just based on whether `$tagt['id_tags']` matches the last element of `$thetag`, not whether it matches any of them. You can solve this by putting `break` after you set `$ceked = "checked";`.

But a simpler way is with:

```
if (in_array($tagt['id_tags'], $thetag)) {
    $aktiv = "active";
    $ceked = "checked";
} else {
    $aktiv = "";
    $ceked = "checked";
}
```